# Triangle area proof

Tags: geometry

Proof that the area of a triangle with sides $2a,2b,2c$ equals $$\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

I have no idea how to tackle this, as I'm not very familiar with proofs. Can anybody gives me some clues/insights on how to tackle this problem?

Comment: This is a version of Herons formula, just fyi in case you werent aware.

Comment: You might want to check [Heron's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron's_formula#Algebraic_proof_using_the_Pythagorean_theorem) out, you can prove this by repeatedly using Pythagoras' Theorem.

Comment: If you want a proof of Herons Formula: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Heron%27s_Formula there you go

Comment: You may also want to see https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0746834212944.di020798.02p0691h.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heron's Formula can be used here.  If a triangle has sides $a,b,c$, then using the semiperimeter $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$, then area of a triangle is 
$$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$
Now, instead of $a,b,c$, substitute in $2a, 2b, $and $2c$.  This also means your semiperimeter is 
$$s=\frac{2a+2b+2c}{2}=a+b+c$$

Thus, 
$$A=\sqrt{s(s-2a)(s-2b)(s-2c)}$$
$$=\sqrt{(a+b+c)(a+b+c-2a)(a+b+c-2b)(a+b+c-2c)}$$
$$=\sqrt{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  In triangle $ABC$, drop a perpendicular from $A$, meeting $BC$ at $X$.  Let $AX,BX,CX$ have lengths $h,x,y$ respectively.  Then
$$x+y=2a\ ,\quad x^2+h^2=4b^2\ ,\quad y^2+h^2=4c^2\ .$$
The area of the triangle is
$$A=ah\ .$$
There is still a fair bit of algebra to do, but see how you go.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Heron's formula for the area of a triangle? Heron's formula is

\begin{equation}
A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}
\end{equation}

where $s:= \frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)$.

For more info. consult http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SSSTheorem.html.